# Minizip: Unzip from buffer?

Tags: c, zip, unzip

Is there any way in Minizip to extract files directly from a buffer? Normally you would use a `unzFile` instance, but that's not an option for me (I get the zipped data directly in a buffer, I don't read it from disk).

Answer (score 1):

From [the authors page](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html):

> Justin Fletcher wrote a very simple implementation of a memory access method for the ioapi code ([ioapi_mem_c.zip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/ioapi_mem_c.zip)).

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use libarchive which is capable of this.